# How to create statistical graphs in WPF, W8 and WP?

Tags: c#, wpf, graph, charts

I've been looking for some libraries and found some very good, but are extra.

- [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/)
- [ComponentOne](http://componentone.com)
- [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com)

Need a free and serve to `WPF`, `Windows 8` and `Windows Phone`.

Greeting.

Comment: Can you elaborate what kind of graphs exactly are you looking for? Histograms? XY plots? Bar charts? Something else?

Comment: Spline area charts, Spline charts, scatter charts, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jorge.

Check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff714591.aspx

Another option is to add the Nugget ZedGraph.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks David. ZedGraph seems a good choice, it fits what I need. Could you teach how to use a manual?

Comment: Thanks David, it really is useful. I downloaded the example but missing a reference WindowsFormsZedGraph.dll and can not find it anywhere

Comment: Please Jorge looking a bit before asking. dll's in the project you just have to add the reference.